Override RabbitMQ Queue Consumers from SpringBoot
I want to know If there is a mechanism with which I can override a consumer listening to a RabbitMQ queue.
For Ex. If there ia a queue named msg.process.1 and a consumer which a container instance is listening to the queue and has the consumer tag as: amq.ctag-AtjZVzgvjUj2uRJKnH-zQw.
If I use the same consumer tag across my different  containers instances, will I be able to override the consumers?
Please let me know If any more information is required.
Thanks in advance.

It sounds more  like abusing the purpose of the consumer tag. See RabbitMQ docs for more info: https://www.rabbitmq.com/docs/consumers#consumer-tags. Apparently this has to be unique per consumer to make all the logic working properly.
